# Unir varias columnas en SQL

Tags: c#, sql

Buen día,

Tengo un query en el modulo de un aplicativo WinForms el cual se encarga de unir 03 campos (razón social, apellido y nombre) en uno solo llamado "apellido_nombre_razon_social". Al cargar mi datagrid, el campo "apellido_nombre_razon_social" me figura vacío, pero si accedo a un registro cualquiera y guardo los cambios en ese punto si se rellena la información en "apellido_nombre_razon_social". Cabe destacar que esto es un campo virtual, no está en el diseño de la tabla. ¿Por que sucede esto? Este problema también pasa si hago la consulta en el propio SQL Server, ahí tampoco me muestra la concatenación de los campos.

```
SELECT Contactos.condicion_id
    ,ContactosCondiciones.condicion
    ,Contactos.contacto_id
    ,Clientes.cliente_id
    ,Contactos.tipo_persona_id
    ,TiposPersonas.tipo_persona
    ,(Contactos.razon_social + SPACE(1) + Contactos.apellido + SPACE(1) + Contactos.nombre) AS apellido_nombre_razon_social
    ,Contactos.razon_social
    ,Contactos.nombre
    ,Contactos.apellido
    ,Contactos.cuit
    ,Contactos.dni
    ,Contactos.fecha
    ,Clientes.sucursal_id
    ,Sucursales.sucursal
    ,Clientes.ejecutivo_id
    ,UsuariosEjecutivos.alias AS ejecutivo
    ,Clientes.auditor_id
    ,UsuariosAuditores.alias AS auditor
    ,Clientes.cierre_ejercicio
    ,Contactos.cuit_fiscal
    ,Contactos.clave_fiscal
    ,Contactos.cuit_agip
    ,Contactos.clave_agip
    ,Contactos.clave_arba
    ,Clientes.medio_pago_id
    ,MediosDePago.medio_pago
    ,Contactos.nacionalidad_id
    ,Paises.pais
    ,Contactos.observaciones
    ,etiqueta
    ,sindicato
FROM Contactos
LEFT OUTER JOIN ContactosCondiciones
    ON ContactosCondiciones.condicion_id = Contactos.condicion_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN TiposPersonas
    ON TiposPersonas.tipo_persona_id = Contactos.tipo_persona_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Clientes
    ON Clientes.contacto_id = Contactos.contacto_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Sucursales
    ON Sucursales.sucursal_id = Clientes.sucursal_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Usuarios AS UsuariosEjecutivos
    ON ejecutivo_id = UsuariosEjecutivos.usuario_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Usuarios AS UsuariosAuditores
    ON auditor_id = UsuariosAuditores.usuario_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Paises
    ON Paises.pais_id = Contactos.nacionalidad_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN MediosDePago
    ON MediosDePago.medio_pago_id = Clientes.medio_pago_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN ClientesEtiquetas
    ON ClientesEtiquetas.contacto_id = Contactos.contacto_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN ClientesSindicatos
    ON ClientesSindicatos.contacto_id = Contactos.contacto_id
ORDER BY TiposPersonas.tipo_persona
    ,apellido_nombre_razon_social ASC;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba esto

```sql
concat(Contactos.razon_social , ' ' , Contactos.apellido , ' ' , Contactos.nombre) AS apellido_nombre_razon_social
```

Comment: Esto funciona bien, lo probé y va genial. Pero quiero encontrarle una explicación lógica a porque cuando actualizo el registro en mi aplicativo, si figura la concatenación en el campo "apellido_nombre_razon_social"

Comment: a que te refieres con 'actualizar'?. Esa parte donde mencionas que accedes a un registro cualquiera y guardas los cambios no me queda clara, no se que es lo que estás haciendo, que estás guardando o a que te refieres con 'actualizar'

Comment: Tengo un modulo de contactos en un aplicativo WinForms, que está desarrollado bajo C#, en el, tengo un gridview en el cual ejecuto este query, dicho query trae diversos contactos, al yo acceder a cualquier contacto (llevarlo a un textbox todos los campos) y hacer un Update, el campo apellido_nombre_razon_social por más que sea un campo virtual se rellena, por eso no le encuentro explicación a que no muestre los datos al principio y al hacer un Update si.